# Google Asynchronous Analytics and Flash AS2

Tags: flash, asynchronous, google-analytics, actionscript-2

OK i inserted the asynchronous code in the published html file just before end of head

In my flash project (which is in actionscript 2) i inserted the as2 code in several buttons like this:

```
on(release){
    getURL("javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/place1/place2.html');");
    gotoAndPlay(frame);
}
```

Shouldn't that work or i need something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, my mistake.
I used the code traditional analytics code in buttons and the asynchronous in html so no communication between swf and script. The right code is something like this:

```
getURL("javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/place1/place2.html']);
```